# How can you get email profile picture from email address?

Tags: javascript, email, gmail, gravatar, inbox

Wondering how you can get an avatar image from an email address. I've seen these options:

- Gravatar
- BIMI

Both seem to not be used universally or in a standardized way. How do Gmail and other providers query for an avatar image from an email address?

Have investigated Gravatar/BIMI.

Comment: [BIMI](https://bimigroup.org/) is an industry group, and its standard may or may not get specified as [RFC](https://bimigroup.org/). BIMI relies in a special DNS entry for the image. Gravatar has an [special URL](https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/) that includes the email address you want to query.